# React Native web app always redirects to "/" location

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm working on an Expo React Native app that's meant to also run on the web. I have an `index.tsx` file that handles my navigation and the authentication. I want users who are logged in to be able to directly visit a URL located at `/payment-success`. However, when users attempt to visit that page directly by typing the URL, it redirects them to "/", AKA the "Root".

I store the tokens with React Native Async Storage. Here's the useEffect that handles authentication:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAccessToken = async () => {
      const token = await tokenService.getAccessTokenAsync();
      if (!token) {
        console.log('Token not found.');
        setLoading(false);
        return;
      }

      const now = new Date();
      const tokenExpiry = await tokenService.getAccessTokenExpiryAsync();
      if (tokenExpiry && now > new Date(tokenExpiry)) {
        console.log(`Token NOT Found.`);
        console.log(`Token Expires At ${tokenExpiry}.`)
        await tokenService.deleteAccessTokenAsync();
        await tokenService.deleteAccessTokenExpiryAsync();
        setLoading(false);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`Token Found.`);
      console.log(`Token Expires At: ${tokenExpiry}`);
      setLoading(false);
      dispatch(setLoggedIn(true));
    }
    checkAccessToken().catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, [])
```

Then, my `index.tsx` for stack navigation looks like this:

```
  const { loggedIn } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user);


  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {!loggedIn &&
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
        </>
      }
      {loggedIn &&
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
          <Stack.Screen name="MakeAPayment" component={MakeAPaymentScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="PaymentSuccess" component={PaymentSuccessScreen} />
        </>
      }
      <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen}  />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

In my linking options I have the screens defined like this:

```
const linking: LinkingOptions<RootStackParamList> = {
  prefixes: [Linking.createURL('/')],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Root: {
        path: 'dashboard',
        screens: {
          Home: {
            screens: {
              HomeScreen: 'home',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      MakeAPayment: 'make-a-payment',
      NotFound: '*',
      PaymentSuccess: 'payment-success',
    },
  },
};

export default linking;
```

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I think it has something to do with "loggedIn" being initialized as `false` in my Redux, but I'm not sure if there's a different fix. I can provide more details if needed